# Multiple Triominos tiling chessboard

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[Where i got the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPRdJ.jpg)

The solution given for tiling a chessboard with 1 tile removed is creating a tiling using induction. I want to know if the tiling is unique. Or the smallest value of n for 2^n × 2^n chessboard with 1 square removed can be tiled by triominos in more than one way.

Comment: Did you search for the result, do you have a picture with one tiling ? Warning : "Search for the result" is not asking to Google, it is search to solve this enigma, by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unique for $2\times 2$ and $4\times 4$ but not bigger, here is example:
[image: tiling as described in article]
Is different from:
[image: tiling different from one found in article]
(ignore the numbers/thick lines plz)

Answer (score 0):

ABCCCDDD

BBCCCDDD

EEFFFGGG

EEFFFGGG

EEHHHIII

JJHHHIII

JJKKKLLL

JJKKKLLL

In this pattern , C is a bloc $3 \times 2$, it can be filled in 2 ways with 2 triominos. Same  for D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L ; so, based on this pattern, we have $2^{10}$ solutions.